# After apt-get autoremove: Missing Operating System

Tags: kernel, grub2, boot-failure

after a
`sudo apt-get upgrade` I was told that some packages could be safely removed. I guess these were old kernels, so I did

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

but now the system won't start anymore and just says `Missing Operating System`.

The computer unfortunately doesn't have a CD drive for a Live CD. I guess I could boot from a USB stick, but what exactly would I then do for a recovery?

Answer (score 2):

**Method 1:** Per [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/)

You can start [Super Grub Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/) via USB

**Methode 2:**

First you need a Live-CD/USB. 
Start the Live-CD and open a new terminal. First mount the Ubuntu-System (boot-partition):

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
```

Here an example for sda2.

Now install GRUB

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt /dev/sda
```